# handling 'res' in Node JS

Tags: node.js

I am relatively new to NodeJS and have run into an issue. Incoming request from Angluar UI has two parameters (loginId and password) and on Node, I am reading the data from a local json file, iterating through the 'users' array and based on the matching params, I am sending the particular object in the server response. However, my logic is failing where there are multiple objects in the 'users' array and I have to send a server response for the not-matched one as well. I know that I cannot send multiple responses but that is where i need the help. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
if (jsonData.users.length > 0) {
            jsonData.users.forEach(user => {
                if ((reqBody.loginId === user.email || reqBody.loginId === user.mobile) && reqBody.password === user.password) {
                    res.send({ 'userData': user });
                } else {
                    res.json({ 'userData': 'No records found' });
                }
            })
```

Comment: "below is a screenshot of the code." - Frightening words

Comment: just replaced the screenshot with code lines as per Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.send` ends the response.
So using it a second time it will not send anything.

https://www.nodejsconnect.com/blog/articles/sending-multiple-http-responses-expressjs

**EDIT:**
I'm not completely sure what you want, but I think you want to do something like this.
-> return the user for whom the userId and password matches or return 'no records found' ( or even better send an 401 - unauthorized - status code)

```
const user = jsonData.users.find(user => (reqBody.loginId === user.email || reqBody.loginId === user.mobile) && reqBody.password === user.password));
if (user) {
    res.send({ 'userData': user });
} else {
    res.json({ 'userData': 'No records found' });
// or res.sendStatus(401); // unauth
}
```

Comment: it goes on and stops my NodeJS server and prints out:

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

my concern is sending response in the 'else' block.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... If you wanna break the loop after a match.

```
if (jsonData.users.length > 0) {
    let isMatch = false;
    jsonData.users.forEach(user => {
        if ((reqBody.loginId === user.email || reqBody.loginId === user.mobile) && reqBody.password === user.password) {
            isMatch = true;
            return res.send({ 'userData': user });
        }
    })
    if(!isMatch)
        res.json({ 'userData': 'No records found' });
}
```

Comment: sending the matched response is working for me anyway, in case when the params do not match, how do i send the response then?

Comment: thank you for this, however, it is returning my query response, also stopping the server and printing the error message:

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Comment: Once again I have made changes. Kindly Check.

Comment: thanks for your time @Meyyappan Subramaniyan. i found the answer.